# wshshell how can we use variable value in .Run

Tags: vbscript

i want to read file line by line and want to use each line as argument in below lines.

```
Set objIniFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile( "C:\Users\rahulsh\Desktop\inputfile.txt",ForReading, False )

Do While objIniFile.AtEndOfStream = False
    strLine = Trim( objIniFile.ReadLine )

    WshShell.Run "cmd /k shutdown -m \\ **-add ""strLine"""**
```

Answer (score 1):

if I understand correctly, this is just a string concatenation of the computer name of the `/m` option of the `shutdown` command

```
Set objIniFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile( "C:\Users\rahulsh\Desktop\inputfile.txt",ForReading, False )

Do While Not objIniFile.AtEndOfStream
    strLine = Trim( objIniFile.ReadLine )

    WshShell.Run "cmd /k shutdown -m \\" & strLine 
loop
```

assuming that strLine will only contain your computer name